# Centre PHP pulled Image

Tags: image, iframe

I have an iframe;

That points to a .php file

and I need the image which is echo'ed to be centred in the iframe.
All the images are 960px  width, but the iframe width needs to be 100% as it will not always be as wide (some pages that it sits on may be 600px wide).

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

PHP
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding     
and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here,     
or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will     
cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can     
escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from     
any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the     
divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with 
side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}
a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers     
around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}
/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of          

selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color: #42413C;
    text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely     
unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}

a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator     
the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds all other elements ~~ */
.container {
    width: 100%; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the     
layout */
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this     
div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in 
mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the     
width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding     
on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the     
padding necessary for your design.

*/
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated     
element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated     
element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element 
following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the 
.container is removed */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}    
    -->
</style></head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <?php
//Sample Database Connection Syntax for PHP and MySQL.
//Connect To Database
$hostname="localhost";
$username="";
$password="";
$dbname="carbonmarketing";
$usertable="ClientList";
$advertfooter = "advertfooter";
mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("    
<html>%MINIFYHTML4333ddb1f6ba50276851b9f9854a5c817%</html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
# Check If Record Exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable
          WHERE region IN ('WW','EU','UK')          
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$advertfooter = $row["$advertfooter"];
echo "$advertfooter";

}
}
?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.CARBONYZED.com/Marketing/UK-Advert_Footer.php" 
style="border:0px  hidden;" name="CARBONMarketingFooter" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Henry

Comment: So you have 960px images wide, that could be seen on 600px wide screens ? that will obviously overflow.. It's not clear to me what problem you want to solve..

Comment: This doesn't sound like a PHP related problem, more like a HTML/CSS related problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty way

```
.content a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
}
```

Comment: Dirty... But it did the trick !!! Perfect. Thanks nvartolomei !!!